# Iterating over output of jq with a for loop in bash

Tags: mongodb, bash, jq

Hello fellow developers !

I'm quite having a hard time on this one, so your help would be good :)

I'm creating a script shell that will periodically (thanks to cron) do a synchronisation between an offline mongodb to firebase.

I use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to treat the export of my mongodb, but this one is acting strangely on strings values containing whitespaces.

For example, I've got this exported document from a mongodb collection named users (using --jsonArray as mongoexport option), file named mycollectionexported.json:

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"5fc253c493b9f7363c8d1011"},"emailVerified":true,"disabled":false,"isKickstarter":false,"isPremiun":false,"gender":"Male","nationality":"None","type":"admin","optMarketing":false,"optNewsletter":false,"cguValidated":true,"providers":[],"email":"test@reflect.com","displayName":"John Doe","phoneNumber":"0644080050","homeAddress":{"street":"rue Pasteur","number":24,"zipcode":94270,"city":"Le Kremlin-Bicêtre","country":"France"},"familyId":{"$oid":"5fc253c493b9f7363c8d1010"},"createdAt":{"$date":"2020-11-28T13:42:28.51Z"},"updatedAt":{"$date":"2020-11-28T13:42:28.51Z"},"__v":0}]
```

You can see that for keys like "displayName", "homeAddress.street" or "homeAddress.city", I've got whitespaces in the values.

When I try to store my newly exported collection into a classic variable using jq, and display it on the stdout, jq is acting quite strangely.

Script executed:

```
#!/bin/bash

documents=$(jq -c ".[]" ./mycollectionexported.json)
for document in $documents; do
  echo ""
  echo $document
done
```

Output:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5fc253c493b9f7363c8d1011"},"emailVerified":true,"disabled":false,"isKickstarter":false,"isPremiun":false,"gender":"Male","nationality":"None","type":"admin","optMarketing":false,"optNewsletter":false,"cguValidated":true,"providers":[],"email":"test@reflect.com","displayName":"John

Doe","phoneNumber":"0644080050","homeAddress":{"street":"rue

Pasteur","number":24,"zipcode":94270,"city":"Le

Kremlin-Bicêtre","country":"France"},"familyId":{"$oid":"5fc253c493b9f7363c8d1010"},"createdAt":{"$date":"2020-11-28T13:42:28.51Z"},"updatedAt":{"$date":"2020-11-28T13:42:28.51Z"},"__v":0}
```

Expected (no newlines):

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5fc253c493b9f7363c8d1011"},"emailVerified":true,"disabled":false,"isKickstarter":false,"isPremiun":false,"gender":"Male","nationality":"None","type":"admin","optMarketing":false,"optNewsletter":false,"cguValidated":true,"providers":[],"email":"test@reflect.com","displayName":"John Doe","phoneNumber":"0644080050","homeAddress":{"street":"rue Pasteur","number":24,"zipcode":94270,"city":"Le Kremlin-Bicêtre","country":"France"},"familyId":{"$oid":"5fc253c493b9f7363c8d1010"},"createdAt":{"$date":"2020-11-28T13:42:28.51Z"},"updatedAt":{"$date":"2020-11-28T13:42:28.51Z"},"__v":0}
```

How is that possible ?
There is no such informations about that in the jq documentation.
When I do it with a json file containing no whitespaces in string values, it works as expected...

Thank you for your help and futures answers :)

Comment: `for document in $documents; do` does not read line-by-line at all; it splits on whitespace, and also tries to expand anything that looks like a filename wildcard pattern (which can have truly bizarre results if there are any matches). See ["Why you don't read lines with `for`"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Yeah it seems that my problem is more on the for loop, and not with jq itself. Thanks for your answer. Stupid error...

Comment: The issue you describe has nothing to do with jq, but with your use of bash variables.  My suggestion would be to read up on bash, and test your understanding without involving jq.

Answer (score -1):

If the output from jq is a single line, why not just:

```
echo "$documents"
```

Or, if the result of the call to jq is a stream that might have more than one item, and if you want each item in the stream to be available as a bash variable, then if your bash is sufficiently up-to-date, you could use `mapfile` (aka `readarray`); otherwise, you could consider using a bash `while` loop, e.g. along the lines of:

```
declare -a document
while read -r item ; do
  document+=("$item")
done < <(jq -c ....)
```

The idea here is that invoking jq with the -c option ensures that the only raw newlines that jq emits will be the ones demarking the items in the stream.